# Order of element of $A_5$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I need to show there is no injective homomorphism $f : D_6 \hookrightarrow A_5$. I know that there is an element of $D_6$ with order 2 (namely $\sigma$, a reflection in some line). If $f$ is a homomorphism, we obtain $f(\sigma)^2 = f(\sigma^2) = f(e_{D_6}) = e_{A_5}$. Hence $f(\sigma)$ is of order 1 or 2. If it is of order 1, $\sigma$ would be an element of ker$(f)$, which would in turn be nontrivial. Therefore, if we demand $f$ to be injective, the order of $f(\sigma)$ must be 2. Now, if I would be able to prove that there *is no* element of order 2 in $A_5$, I would be done. My gut tells me that is indeed the case, since $A_5$ is generated by the 3-cycles. The proof however, eludes me.

Comment: $D_6$ has $6$ or $12$ elements?

Comment: The element $(12)(34) \in A_5 < S_5$ has order $2$.

Comment: @Jos van Nieuwman: Since you got an answer, you could accept quasi's post and remove your question from the list of **open** problems.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

$D_6$ has an element of order $6$, but the only elements $x\in S_5$ of order $6$ have disjoint cycle representation of the form $x=(a\;b\;c)(d\;e)$ which is the product of the even element $(a\;b\;c)$, and the odd element $(d\;e)$, so $x$ is odd, hence $x\notin A_5$.

Note that $|A_5|=60$, hence $A_5$ *does* have elements of order $2$, since any group of even order has an element of order $2$. Explicitly, if $x,y\in S_5$ are disjoint $2$-cycles, and $z=xy$, then $z$ has order $2$, and $z$ is even, so $z\in A_5$.

Comment: I see, except for the fact that _every_ $x \in S_5$ of order 6 has the cycle representation you describe. It is intuitively clear, but I haven't verified it..

Comment: The order of an element of $S_n$ is the least common multiple of the orders of the disjoint cycles in its disjoint cycle representation (since disjoint cycles commute). If an element $x$ of $S_5$ is not a cycle, then it must be the product of two  nontrivial disjoint cycles, so the disjoint cycles representation of $x$ either has the form $(a\;b)(c\;d)$, which has order $\text{lcm}(2,2)=2$, or else has the form $(a\;b\;c)(d\;e)$, which has order $\text{lcm}(2,3)=6$.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I now realise that that is actually a proof. Thanks for the quick response!